# Generate true or false boolean with a probability

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, math, random

I have a percentage, for example `40%`. Id like to "*throw a dice*" and the outcome is based on the *probability*. (for example there is `40%` chance it's going to be `true`).

Comment: `Random random = new Random();...bool result = random.NextDouble() <= 0.40;`

Comment: I have a forge system with probability. When I click to forge an item, there is a determined chance the item will be forged, or the forge will fail. That's what Im trying to do.

Comment: There is also a stack exchange for game developers. Loads of unity experts there. Just thought I mention it.

Answer (score 8):

Since `Random.NextDouble()` returns uniformly distributed in `[0..1)` range (pseudo)random value, you can try

```
 // Simplest, but not thread safe   
 private static Random random = new Random();

 ...

 double probability = 0.40;

 bool result = random.NextDouble() < probability;
```

Comment: I wish I could upvote twice, once for being the correct answer and a second time for using the proper mathematical notation for an interval.

Comment: Super-nitpick: I believe `<` is more appropriate than `<=` here, since you want the edge-cases of `probability = 0.0` and `probability =1.0` to translate to "never" and "always". With `<=`, there's a nonzero chance of `result` being true when `probability = 0.0`.

Comment: @Mark Dickinson: THank you! I agree with your counter example: usually including/excluding point doesn't play any role since probability of the *exact* value is *zero*. However, we don't have *perfect* uniform distribution with `random.NextDouble()` and `probability = 0.0` is a counter example. I've edited my answer

Answer (score 3):

You can try something like this:

```
    public static bool NextBool(this Random random, double probability = 0.5)
    {
        if (random == null)
        {
            throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(random));
        }

        return random.NextDouble() <= probability;
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use the built-in [`Random.NextDouble()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-US/library/system.random.nextdouble(v=vs.110).aspx):

> Returns a random floating-point number that is greater than or equal to 0.0, and less than 1.0

Then you can test whether the number is greater than the probability value:

```
static Random random = new Random();

public static void Main()
{
    // call the method 100 times and print its result...
    for(var i = 1; i <= 100; i++)
        Console.WriteLine("Test {0}: {1}", i, ForgeItem(0.4));
}

public static bool ForgeItem(double probability)
{
    var randomValue = random.NextDouble();
    return randomValue <= probability;
}
```

Take note the **same `Random` instance** must be used. [Here is the Fiddle example](https://dotnetfiddle.net/YbDTBa).

Answer (score 1):

Simple Unity solution:

```
bool result = Random.Range(0f, 1f) < probability;
```